# Pushing react app to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

Ok so I've never actually deployed an app before. I used the create-react-app to create the app, when ready I used `npm run build` this gives me a build folder but when I try to push the code to my github repo it says everything is up-to-date.

Should I be just concerned with the the build folder now? I tried creating a repo for my build folder and deploying it to Heroku but that didn't work.

I'm not sure how to get my code up to github and then to Heroku if it's saying everything is up to date. Just looking for some feedback here. Haven't really deployed anything before.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the build directory in your .gitignore file?  That might be the reason why Git is not seeing your changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the [create-react-app-buildpack](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)

Set the buildpack with

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack
```

Then just push to heroku and you're good to go!

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an another repo with heroku using their cli and run these commands:

`heroku login`

`heroku create`

Then copy the second link which is your heroku git repo and push your code using:

`git push heroku master`